# Big O Notation Explain?

Tags: big-o

When I take the Algorithm course in Coursera, I met a question about Big-O notation that says O(n2) = O(n). I check some other answers in Stack overflow and some posts said that Big Notation means the "upper bound".  Based on this def: could I sai O(n) = O(2^n) because O(n)<= O(2^n)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEioK.png)

Comment: no it means whats the worst outcome of time my code can take if i put n amount of something in it so the upper boundary refers to the upper boundary of time it would take to complete in the worst case

Comment: so for example if I have a simple for loop that iterates through an array and randomly stops at some element the worst runtime would be iterating through the entire thing and stopping at the last (nth ) element so it yields O(n)

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 0):

In some cases polynomials are considered pretty much equivalent with regards to anything exponential.

But most probably 2 was a scalar, O(2*N) is the same as O(N) because constant factors are usually ignored in big O notation.

In any case, no O(n) and O(2 to the n) are not =, O(n) is however a subset of O(higher order N).

Comment: scalars can be important in some cases though oO (even though I cant remember one of the top of my head)
oh for example iterating over an array twice to do something versus managing it one one iteration :P

Comment: well if the constant factor K becomes high enough that N^(N-1)*K contests with N^N, then it can be useful to take K into consideration. But that means lower order O(N^x) with low x complexity at least, and short examples (N is by hypothesis able to always make K negligible in the worst case)

Comment: or as in your example if comparing algorithms with the same polynomial highest degree, the K multpilying the highest degree is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It would be inappropriate to say O(n) *equals* O(n^2).  Rather, say, O(n) *falls within the bounds of* O(n^2).